# How can i create plugin to sell my products on other websites?

Tags: node.js, api, plugins, e-commerce

I have an eCommerce website. I want to let other websites sell my products on their website,

also, I want it to be as automatic as possible,
something like google ads - where the other website just needs to add one line of code,
how can i do that?
and how to keep track of my products (and take my money & give them their commission)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 2 scenarios for example:

1. You want a rest api that could be implemented by other 3rd party sellers that could be called by them in order for you to keep track of purchases and their comissions. ( in this case the final customer will remain on 3rd party seller webpage )
2. If you insist on adding something like google ads on a seller webpage in that case you can play with cookies meaning:

Customer enters on seller website he will see something like an "ad" he or she will click on that ad ( image/link ) and will be redirected to your site https://yourwebsite.com/redirectedFrom=seller123

You will save that seller123 in customer cookie browser and if that customer will purchase something from your website you will know from cookie saved earlier from which seller customer was coming in order for you to assign commission and so on.

I hope that both scenarios might help. It really depends on you if you want that a customer should order something directly from other 3rd party seller or directly from your website.

To be more specific in both situations you will end up making money but both scenarios has different customer experience, on 1st scenario customer remains on seller website on 2nd one customer will be redirected to your website

Comment: i want to sell the items on their website, but how can i know if their user bought the item? even if I will make them add a javascript file or something i still cant know if the user bought the item or not, and i dont want to make it for specific website - i want it to be as automatic as possible

Comment: That's why I mentioned that you have to build a REST Api ... that Rest API you will host and integrate with your website ( to control purchases, comissions and so on ) ... 

And sellers website will call your rest api through maybe a HTTP Post Request ex; 

{ "itemId": 5, "sellerId": "seller123", "status": "purchased" }  

This message will be sent by seller website to your rest api and in this way you will know which items was purchased from which seller and other stuff that you might need